# C++ streams and iterators: Why does this only print once?

Tags: c++, stream, iterator

I was just messing around with some streams and iterators and all was fine until I tried the code below. I am expecting the output to be all the words from the input file printed line by line. I know I could just use the >> operator on the ifstream but I was just writing this code to get a better grasp of streams and iterators. The current output that I'm getting is all the words of line one printed on their own line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
   if (argc < 3) {
      std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " INPUT_FILE OUTPUT_FILE" << std::endl;
   }
   std::string line;
   std::istringstream iss;
   std::ifstream ifs;

   ifs.open(argv[1]);

   while ( getline(ifs, line) ) {
      iss.str(line);
      std::cout << iss.str(); //debug
      std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
            std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
   }

   ifs.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Reset the error flags for your `std::istringstream`:

```
while ( getline(ifs, line) ) {
      iss.clear();
      iss.str(line);
      ...
}
```

Your call to `std::copy` exhausts the underlying buffer and your `std::istringstream` object is in a fail state (eofbit set).

Comment: Define and construct `iss` in the loop.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Why would that be better?

Comment: Because it would ensure that `iss` has a clean state.  It's not obvious how to clear all possible state otherwise.

Comment: @JamesKanze: That maybe a valid point, but it might also be preferable to avoid construction/destruction for every loop.

Comment: Why?  If you want a clean, new instance, the best way to get it is to construct a clean, new instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should define `iss` in the loop.  You need a new, clean one
each time through the loop:

```
while ( std::getline( ifs, line ) ) {
    std::istringstream iss( line );
    //  ...
}
```

Otherwise, `iss` retains state from it's previous uses, which
you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

If you read e.g. [this reference of `std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) you will see that it uses `operator>>` to get the input, and `operator>>` reads only white-space delimited entries. That's why you get each word on separate lines.

And you won't be able to read the input string stream more than once because once it's done it's EOF flag is set. Either clear the flags, or declare the string stream object inside the loop.

Comment: Does anyone know how to effectively clear _all_ of the flags?  (In this simplified case, it's fairly obvious, but in general?)

Answer (score 0):

```
   while ( getline(ifs, line) ) {
      iss.str(line);
      std::cout << iss.str(); //debug
      std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
            std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
            iss.clear(); // celar the iss to reset flags
   }
```